# TensorFlow estimator.predict() gives WARNING:tensorflow:Input graph does not contain a QueueRunner

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to get a prediction with a custom input function with `estimator.predict`, but it gives me this:

`WARNING:tensorflow:Input graph does not contain a QueueRunner. That means predict yields forever. This is probably a mistake.`

It doesn't give me an error, but `predict` just says that its restoring parameters and doesn't return the actual predictions. Here is my code:

```
test_data = [0.03, 0.91, 0.95, 0.10, 0.56, 0.93]
test_data_in = { k: test_data[index] for index, k in enumerate(FEATURES) }
print(test_data_in)

def predict_input_fn(data_set):
    feature_cols = { k: tf.reshape(tf.constant(data_set[k], dtype=tf.float32), [-1]) for k in FEATURES }
    return feature_cols

predictions = estimator.predict(input_fn=lambda: predict_input_fn(test_data_in))
print(list(predictions))
```

I've looked at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11621) issue, but I couldn't find a solution related to my problem. Why does TensorFlow show this warning and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: damn, just found this (hitting the same issue), and no answers?

Comment: Maybe not useful (it wasn't for me): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hit this too, reading the thread https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11621

> I think your program is perfectly correct and it's the warning that's wrong :). It was added long before the Datasets API existed, and was well intentioned. (AFAICT the predict() API relies on your input terminating with a tf.errors.OutOfRangeError and before Datasets existed only QueueRunner-based pipelines would terminate that way, so it probably was an error if no queue runners existed.)
>   @xiejw Should we remove this warning, or is there a more cunning way to detect the error condition?

Hopefully they will remove the error when it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Until they change the behaviour of this warning, here's a quick patch to suppress it:

```
tf.estimator.Estimator._validate_features_in_predict_input = lambda *args: None
```

Include this line after importing `tensorflow`.

It shouldn't have any unintended side effects, but have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L982) if you want to convince yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. However, to see the values in prediction (row by row), I made use of `__next__()` operator.
Thus, the code to display next immediate row is: `print(predictions.__next__)`